# Replae last occurrence of specific digit inside square brackets

Tags: regex

I need to find last digit from string and I am stuck.

Could you please tell me how do I replace last 0 from following string:

```
something[0].moresomething[0].evenmoresomething
```

Comment: An example of what you want go from and too would be useful.  I'm guessing you mean replace the second [0] with something maybe [x]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\[)0(?=\])(?!.*?\[0\])
```

It will match last `0` in `[]`

Answer (score 5):

This would get you the last digit... also known as a '[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)'.

```
\d(?!.*\d)
```

If you're doing this in .NET, to replace the last character you'd do something like:

```
string source = "something[0].moresomething[0].evenmoresomething";
string regEx = @"\d(?!.*\d)";
string result = Regex.Replace(source, regEx, "2");
```

'result' would now contain the string "something[0].moresomething[2].evenmoresomething"

Comment: You can drop the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
\d(\D*)$
```

and replace with whatever you want and `$1`

This will work if your number is really the last one in the string/row. (See Kirills example in the comment).

See [it here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2umva)

`$1` is here the content of the first capturing group. that means the content of the `()`, i.e. everything thats following the digit you want to replace.

`\d` is a digit

`\D` is not a digit

`$` is the end of the string

Comment: Try input like: `something[0].moresomething[0].evenmore0something`